# Refreshing jTable with Database with Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing a database application with Java and with MySQL as database.
Am using Netbeans as a developing Tool.

I need to display the stored database in a JTable.

Now when I add data to the database via query. The JTable is not showing the updated details instantly. I need to restart the application i.e. run it again.

Now I need to know how do I refresh the JTable when there is a change in DB.

Please provide me the steps or sample coding because I am not able to find a certain coding example on Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's enough to fire changes through the table model:

```
yourTable.getModel().fireTableDataChanged()
```

Comment: its not working the fireTableDataChaged() method is not getting detected

Comment: useless post, please edit your post and add something about JTable, TableModel ..., and nobody knows what's OP's developing Tool

Answer (score 2):

Whenever data in the database changes you need to recreate the TableModel and then update the table with the new model:

TableModel model = ...

```
table.setModel( model );
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, then i created the function named "UPDATEtable()"
in which I put the connectivity code and called that function when it was needed to input data in Jtable from Mysql. For Refresh button , i first cleared the data from the table and then called the same function.

Here is the code :-(Table Variable name - TB1)

```
private void **UPDATEtable()**{
        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) TB1.getModel();
try{



  stmt= con.createStatement();
    String query="SELECT * FROM goods ORDER BY order_num DESC;";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
        String PID = rs.getString("PID");
     String Pname = rs.getString("Pname");
       String NUM = rs.getString("order_num");
      model.addRow(new Object[] {PID ,Pname,NUM);

    }


}


catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.print(e);

}
```

**FOR REFRESH BUTTON :-**

```
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) TB1.getModel();
        while(model.getRowCount()>0){
    model.setRowCount(0);
}

        UPDATEtable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following code if you have instanciated tableNameList as observable:

```
tableNameList.clear();
tableNameList.addAll(tableQuery.getResultList());
```

Comment: Yes, it is right but only if you have instanciated tableNameList as observable.